# Why this code is running without errors ? Reverse a link list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a linked list, write a function to reverse every k nodes (where k is an input to the function).

```
Examples:

Inputs:  1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->NULL and k = 3 
Output:  3->2->1->6->5->4->8->7->NULL. 

Inputs:   1->2->3->4->5->6->7->8->NULL and k = 5
Output:  5->4->3->2->1->8->7->6->NULL.
```

**This is the Code:**

```
# Node class 
class Node: 

    # Constructor to initialize the node object 
    def __init__(self, data): 
        self.data = data 
        self.next = None

class LinkedList: 

    # Function to initialize head 
    def __init__(self): 
        self.head = None

    def reverse(self, head, k): 
        current = head 
        Next = None
        prev = None
        count = 0

        # Reverse first k nodes of the linked list 
        while(current is not None and count < k): 
            Next = current.next
            current.next = prev 
            prev = current 
            current = Next
            count += 1

        # next is now a pointer to (k+1)th node 
        # recursively call for the list starting 
        # from current . And make rest of the list as 
        # next of first node 
        if Next is not None: 
            head.next = self.reverse(Next, k) 

        # prev is new head of the input list 
        return prev 

    # Function to insert a new node at the beginning 
    def push(self, new_data): 
        new_node = Node(new_data) 
        new_node.next = self.head 
        self.head = new_node 

    # Utility function to print the linked LinkedList 
    def printList(self): 
        temp = self.head 
        while(temp): 
            print temp.data, 
            temp = temp.next


# Driver program 
llist = LinkedList() 
llist.push(9) 
llist.push(8) 
llist.push(7) 
llist.push(6) 
llist.push(5) 
llist.push(4) 
llist.push(3) 
llist.push(2) 
llist.push(1) 

print "Given linked list"
llist.printList() 
llist.head = llist.reverse(llist.head, 3) 

print "\nReversed Linked list"
llist.printList()
```

On my computer, this code gives me error saying `"LinkedList class has no attribute next"` => the error in this statement `"Next = current.next"` . On [Geeks for Geeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-list-in-groups-of-given-size/) the code is running fine. Also on all the online IDEs the code is running fine. So is it something wrong with my device or the code should not run ?

Comment: It doesn't sound like you're running the code you think you are.

Comment: Are you sure you are running the same code everywhere?

Comment: next "N" is capital in some of your code

Comment: @user2357112 Should not the code through an error anyway? since LinkedList class has no attribute `.next` ?

Comment: The posted code doesn't try to access a `next` attribute of a `LinkedList` object.

Comment: @user2357112 the first thing `reverse` function will do is to take the `head` that is passed to the function which is of type `LinkedList` and assign it to `current` then `current.next` How is this possible while `current` became a type of class `LinkedList`

Comment: @ananya no because you are passing in `llist.head` which is a Node object which has a `next` attribute

Comment: @Vaibhav Thank you. I got it. Thank you all. Appreciate the help!